# Is it possible to mount an ATA over Ethernet (AOE) block device on multiple clients, if so how?

Tags: array, storage, cluster, san, gfs

I have a lab consisting of 3 machines connected with 2 10gbe links on 2 segregated networks. Each device has 100tb in block storage connected to it. I want to use ATA over Ethernet to create a storage cluster which can be accessed from all the machines at one time. I want to do this from both the client and initiators at the same time.

I want to be able to mount the target file system on multiple initiators.  I do not need to write to the filesystem from multiple systems at once, but I do want to read from the file system from many at once. I have thought about creating cache devices, though i would like to avoid this if possible.  I know this is a rather complex problem, but I feel like i'm missing something, as it seems like what I want should be possible.  I have been playing around but have not come up with a good plan on how to do this. I've setup a target using vblade, and accessed that from a separate system; however I'm unable to access it from the host, if I access it from 2 initiators at once then it seems to become corrupted of course.

Additionally, I am not sure what filesystem i can use which will allow what I want without becoming corrupted. I tried btrfs, xfs, zfs... I am thinking maybe I am going about it wrong, so thought I'd write this post and see if anyone can share some ideas.  I think i need to use GFS but I haven't been able to get it setup correctly.

**So my question is if it possible to access the same disk from two systems at the same time using AOE?**

*relevant stuff:*

- I do not want to use nfs, samba, ssh, or any of these options.
- Security is not a concern it is on a closed internal air-gapped network.
- Yes I've searched but it is hard to find relevant info.
- the systems are each have 2 10gbe links, one for tcp/ip, one for ata over ethernet.
- I'm open to suggestions, but I don't especially want to have to code
  a new solution, and want to stick with open source software.
- I apologize in advance for my poorly written question.

Comment: [Gluster](https://www.gluster.org/) on top of ZFS, or [Ceph](https://ceph.io/) are two good open-source options.   [DRBD](https://www.drbd.org/) may also be worth considering if RAID-1 over your network is adequate for your needs (it probably isn't).  All of these will require at least one of the machines to act as a server (but high-availability can be achieved by having two, or all, of the lab machines performing that role)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions.  I will take a look at these, more... I have seen gluster and ceph but haven't tested either.  I am still experimenting and will post back if/when I make some progress.